# Extracting value from delegated function Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I need help concerning the logic behind a problem I have regarding delegate and protocol. I made a timer app that allows you set a timer. The timer selection is within SettingsController and I used protocols and delegates to pass data into my TimerController. This works as the timer change. But I am having problems concerning creating the logic for the reset button. I want the reset button to have the same data. Example, if I choose 5mins as the timer, the reset button will reset as 5min. Currently its reseting to 0. The problem is really extracting the data from the delegated function into the TimerController so I can change the value of counter which is nil.

**SettingsController**

```
import UIKit

protocol SettingsVCDelegate {

func didSelectReadingSpeed(counter: Int)
}

class SettingsVC: UIViewController {

var counter = Int()
var settingsDelegate: SettingsVCDelegate!

@IBAction func changeReadingSpeed(_ sender: UISlider) {

    speedSlider.value = roundf(speedSlider.value)

    if speedSlider.value == 1 {
        speedLabel.text = "1 min (60 pgs / hr) Extreme"
        counter = 1
        print(counter)
    } else if speedSlider.value == 2 {
        speedLabel.text = "2 min (30 pgs / hr) Fast"
        counter = 2
    }
}

@IBAction func didTappedStart(_ sender: Any) {
    settingsDelegate.didSelectReadingSpeed(counter: counter)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**TimerController**

```
class TimerController: UIViewController, CountdownTimerDelegate, SettingsVCDelegate {

lazy var countdownTimer: CountdownTimer = {
    let countdownTimer = CountdownTimer()
    return countdownTimer
}()

var resetBtn: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetBtnDidTouch), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func resetBtnDidTouch() {
    countdownTimer.reset()
    countdownTimer.setMinuteTimer(minutes: 0, seconds: counter)
    countdownTimer.setHourTimer(hour: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: duration)
}

var counter = Int()
var isRunning = false 
var resumeTapped = false

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    countdownTimer.delegate = self
    countdownTimer.setMinuteTimer(minutes: 0, seconds: counter)
    countdownTimer.setHourTimer(hour: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: duration)     

}

   //MARK: - Settings Delegate

func didSelectReadingSpeed(counter: Int) {
    let counter = counter
    countdownTimer.setMinuteTimer(minutes: 0, seconds: counter)
}
```

Very much appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: I'm new to programming so I'd also appreciate it if you can explain the logic behind it and why it's the case.   :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. It's disrespectful to dump whole classes and make people read through code that has nothing to do with what you're asking. Please read [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: oh sorry about that! I didn't know the etiquette regarding usage of stack overflow. I thought by giving more code, people will understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using three(!) `counter` variables in your code

1. The property on the top level
2. The parameter in `didSelectReadingSpeed`
3. The local variable in `didSelectReadingSpeed`

This is pretty confusing because all three objects are different. To avoid the naming confusion name the parameter in the delegate method `speed` (you could even omit `Speed` in the method name) for example

```
protocol SettingsVCDelegate {
    func didSelectReading(speed: Int)
}
```

The issue occurs because the property whose value is used to reset the timer **never** changes.

Solution: When the delegate method is called delete the ***local variable*** `counter` and assign `speed` to the ***property*** `counter`.

```
func didSelectReading(speed: Int) {
    counter = speed
    countdownTimer.setMinuteTimer(minutes: 0, seconds: counter)
}
```

---

Two notes:

- Don't initialize a *scalar* property with the default initializer e.g. `Int()`, assign a default value which is more descriptive:
  `var counter = 0`.
- Initializing `countdownTimer` with a closure looks pretty cool but it's pointless if the property is only initialized.
  `lazy var countdownTimer = CountdownTimer()` does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Assigning "speed" to the property counter worked. This helped a lot and it solved my problems! But before changing the parameter to speed, I did assign counter = counter, instead of counter = speed. Shouldn't this have worked despite the confusion? But when assigning counter = counter, I get the error "Cannot assign to value: "counter" is a 'let' constant.". How is this possible when the property is set to var.

Comment: So how did just changing the parameter fixed my problem?

Comment: That's the confusion. The left side of `let counter = counter` is the local variable which you just declared, **it is not the property**. They are completely different objects. The right side is the delegate method parameter which is also different from the property **and** the local variable. Local variables with the same name as properties hide the property. If you want to access the property write `self.counter = counter`

Comment: but I'm talking about not declaring the local variable. Instead of "let counter = counter" can't we do it as "counter = counter"? Wouldn't this make the property = to the parameter?

Comment: No, `counter = counter` tries to reassign the delegate method parameter. Once again, you have to add `self` to address the property to get rid of this ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer. Additionally, you declared and initialized "counter" as a minute.

`countdownTimer.setMinuteTimer(minutes: counter, seconds: 0)` should be in this way or if "counter" declared as a seconds:

```
minutes = counter / 60
seconds = counter % 60
```